# Rust Box and move

Tags: rust, move, smart-pointers

I have the following code:

```rust
use std::{borrow::BorrowMut, mem};

struct Node {
    ele: i32,
    next: List,
}

enum List {
    Empty,
    More(Box<Node>),
}

pub struct LinkedList {
    head: List,
}

impl LinkedList {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        LinkedList { head: List::Empty }
    }

    pub fn push(&mut self, value: i32) {
        let new_node = Box::new(Node {
            ele: value,
            next: mem::replace(self.head.borrow_mut(), List::Empty),
        });

        self.head = List::More(new_node);
    }

    pub fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<i32> {
        match mem::replace(self.head.borrow_mut(), List::Empty) {
            List::Empty => None,
            List::More(node) => { // node have type Box<Node>
                self.head = node.next;
                Some(node.ele)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I change `List::More(node) => {` to `List::More(ref node) => {`, will produce the error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `node.next` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/first.rs:35:29
   |
35 |                 self.head = node.next;
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `node.next` has type `List`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

It seems that the move occurs in line 35. My questions are:

- Does a move occurred before I changed?
- Why it works before I changed?

In fact, I'm reading ["Learn Rust by writing Entirely Too Many Linked Lists"](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/). I noticed that in [this commit](https://github.com/rust-unofficial/too-many-lists/commit/791f848108772b280d6592e20bade22e344829e5#diff-efdf2ac6b9c312446a5a5c4a8bf632e423e6f6ed37ecb0cfea20cb53bc31eca0L247-R277), the committer changed something to updating to rust 2018. These changes seem to related to my question.

Comment: With the original, `List::More(node)`, pattern, `node` is (as you have commented) of type `Box<Node>`: that is, the `Box` is *owned by* `node` and thus there is no problem moving `.next` out from it; with the changed, `List::More(ref node)`, pattern, `node` is of type `&Box<Node>` and the move is not possible.

Comment: To put it another way, moving a value out of a field, such as moving something from `node.next` invalidates the whole value. You are free to invalidate the values you own (because you could drop them whenever you wanted anyway), but not the values you borrow - because there owner and/or other borrows expect the value to remain usable.

Answer (score 0):

`self.head` is of type `List`, as declared in `struct List { ... }`. Therefore, an *owned* `List` must be assigned to `self.head`. `&List` and `&mut List` are not owned, but references. So when assigning to `self.head`, you must have *ownership* of the value you want to assign. If you change the match arm to `List::More(ref node) => {`, `node` is of type `&List`, which is a *reference* and not an owned value and therefore not assignable to `self.head`.